# How to find the negative weight between two adjacent nodes in python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Hi i have a big text file with format like this:

```
1  3  1
2  3  -1
5  7  1
6  1  -1
3  2  -1
```

the first column is the starting node, the second column the ending node and the third column shows the sign between two nodes. So i have positive and negative signs.
Im reading the graph with the code below:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.read_edgelist('network.txt', delimiter='\t', nodetype=int, data=(('weight', int),))
print(nx.info(G))
```

I also found a function to find the neighbors of a specific node:

```
list1 = list(G.neigbors(1))
```

So i have a list with the adjacency nodes of node 1. How can a find the sign between the node 1 and each adjacency node? (For example that edge between 1-3 has sign 1, the edge 1-5 has sign -1 etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example for node `1`:

```
n_from = 1
for n_to in G.neighbors(n_from):
    sign = G[n_from][n_to]['weight']

    print('edge from {} to {} has sign {}'.format(
        n_from, n_to, sign))
```

which prints, for the example input you gave:

> edge from 1 to 3 has sign 1 
>   edge from 1 to 6 has sign -1

A similar approach, treating `G[n_from]` as a *dict*:

```
n_from = 1
for n_to, e_data in G[n_from].items():
    sign = e_data['weight']
    # then print
```

You can alternatively use `Graph.get_edge_data`, as such:

```
e_data = G.get_edge_data(n_from, n_to)
sign = e_data.get('weight')
```